# cvtColor ignores dstCn argument OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to create a program which imports an RGB image and converts it to grayscale. I would like the output image to consist of 3 channels. To achieve that I use `cv::cvtColor` function with `dstCn` parameter set to 3:

```cpp
cv::Mat mat = cv::imread("lena.bmp");
std::cout << CV_MAT_CN(mat.type()) << "\n"; // prints "3", OK
cv::cvtColor(mat, mat, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY, 3);
std::cout << CV_MAT_CN(mat.type()) << "\n"; // prints "1" regardless of dstCn
```

but it looks like `dstCn` isn't taken into account, and the output array has only 1 channel.

[The OpenCV documentation says](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html#ga397ae87e1288a81d2363b61574eb8cab):

> dstCn - number of channels in the destination image; if the parameter is 0, the number of the channels is derived automatically from src and code.

It's a very basic case and I am aware there are plenty of workarounds, but I would like to know whether it is a bug or my incomprehension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer can be found in the OpenCV source code. Let's have a look at `cvtColor` function in *[imageproc/src/color.cpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/941a9792f7c7d60640c82926091d710e6ecbfb55/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp#L178)* file. There is a very long switch-case, so I only post here the most interesting part:

```cpp
void cvtColor( InputArray _src, OutputArray _dst, int code, int dcn )
{
    ...
    switch( code )
    {
    ...
    case COLOR_BGR2GRAY: case COLOR_BGRA2GRAY:
    case COLOR_RGB2GRAY: case COLOR_RGBA2GRAY:
        cvtColorBGR2Gray(_src, _dst, swapBlue(code));
        break;
    }
}
```

The code from my question uses `COLOR_BGR2GRAY`. Nothing special is done before the switch statement. Invoking `swapBlue` does not do anything interesting too. We can see that this case completely ignores `dcn` (aka `dstCn`). So it seems to be fully intentional and my idea was wrong from the start.

I have also found [a similar post on OpenCV forum](https://answers.opencv.org/question/64354/whats-the-best-way-to-create-a-3-channel-grayscale-from-bgr/) where *Doomb0t* pointed that:

> the concept of greyscale is that you have one channel describing the intensity on a gradual scale between black and white. So, it is not clear why would you need a 3 channels greyscale image (...)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, grayscale is one channel and what you ask doesn't make sense at first sight, however there could be a legit reason if you want it copied in three channels in one operation and then manipulate each of the copies, while they are kept in the same container.

swapBlue is because default format is BGR.

BTW, you can also read it directly in blackwhite and merge it into new 3 channel image:

```
cv::Mat bw = cv.imread("lena.bmp",0);
vector<Mat> ch(3);
bw3 = Mat::zeros(Size(bw.cols, bw.rows), CV_8UC3); //3 channels 8 bit unsigned
for(i=0; i<3; i++) ch.push_back(bw)
cv.merge(ch, bw3)
```

(Maybe there's a shorter way, I don't know.)

[More examples with merge](https://cppsecrets.com/users/203110310511410511510410011599115495764103109971051084699111109/C00-OpenCV-cvmerge.php)